# How to Lambda thread body

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a class that currently uses a class method as the thread body:

```
    class Something {
    public:
        bool isRunning() { return m_run; }

    private:
        void threadBody(void);

        std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;
        std::atomic<bool> m_run;
    };
```

There is a lot more to the class than just the simple example above, the current code looks something like this:

```
  Something::Something() : m_run(true) {
      m_thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>(std::bind(&Something::threadBody, this));
  }
```

The class method "threadBody" looks something like this:

```
  void Something::threadBody(void) {
      while( m_run ) {
            //Do something here until m_run is false
      }
  }
```

Now I've been asked to convert the thread body to Lambda, I'm reading up on how to do this and looking for help on how I achieve the same.

How do I pass the instance of the class so that its members can be accessed in the body of the thread?

Would this be correct?

```
    m_thread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([this](Something* pInstance) {
        while( pInstance->isRunning ) {
        //Do something here until m_run is false
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you give an idea of why you wan't to change to Lambda? Should the thread function be more like a free function, or could the lambda be defined within the class?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, the thread body.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, sorry I don't know the answer to why?  I was asked to do it and thats all.

Comment: Any reason why your are storing the thread in a `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: To be honest the first version of the code was developed by another, I've just picked it up to update.  Although that said I have ditched the std::unique_ptr as it introduces other problems.

Comment: Then now is your chance to improve it!

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, doing that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the parameter - you're capturing `this` and since the lambda is defined in the scope of the class you have the normal accessibility inside a member definition:

```
[this]() {
    while (m_run) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So it sounds like you want to do away with the class. I guess I would suggest something like the following:

```
    std::atomic<bool> finish{false}; 
    std::thread t1 {[&finish]() {          
        unsigned counter = 0;
        while (!finish) {    
            std::cout << "Run " << counter++ << "\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        }
    }};

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    finish = true;
    t1.join();
```

Here i have made 2 important changes:

1. The class is gone and your thread body (do something) is a lambda.
2. Use an `atomic<bool>` for your `finish loop` flag to avoid unsafe thread behaviour.

[Here is a live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f46b97061399837)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly pass "this" as a parameter if you are already capturing it.  Not sure why you need it to be `unique_ptr`.

Simpler:

```
class Something {
        ...
        std::thread m_thread;

     };
```

Constructor:

```
Something::Something() : m_run(true) {
      m_thread = std::thread([this]() {
          while (isRunning()) {
             // Do Something
          }
      });
  }
```